# Random num in a label-iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

What am I doing wrong here? I'm not getting the randomNum value displayed when I run in simulator.. (I've already linked everything in IB). (Edit: Actually the program just crashes now)

```
.m file:

randomNum=arc4random() % 100;
randomNumLabel.text=randomNum;  

.h file:
int randomNum;
int guess;
IBOutlet UITextField *numberField;
IBOutlet UILabel *randomNumLabel;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to convert the number to a string by using `NSString`'s `stringWithFormat:` method.

```
randomNumLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", randomNum];
```